# Why Rails Console is Multiplying Wrong?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, math

I have a problem : 
In **rails console**, when I do 17.90*100 and result 1789.9999999999998

Please explain why it is happening?

Thank you !!

Comment: use BigDecimal.

Comment: Welcome to the wild world of floating point math.